# Hover styles are being applied on mobile view when I tap the elements and stay in "hover" state until I click out

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

The main problem is that hover styles are being applied on mobile web, even though hover state shouldn't exist in touch devices at all?

Second problem is that even though tap is being treated as hover, I wouldn't mind if the hover state dissapeared after the tap, however at the moment once I tap the element, the hover styles remain applied, until i tap somewhere else?

Here is my simple code that causes this:

```
          <button className="hover:bg-gray-700">Regular button</button>
```

Solutions that I have tried:

1. Adding this line to my tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true
  },
```

2. Adding this line to my tailwind.config.js

```
    extend: {
      screens: {
        support: { raw: '(hover: hover)' } // check if hover is supported on the device
      },
```

None of these solutions solved my problem.

What else can I try to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since hover states are active when hovering over the specified object, they do not work as we expect on mobile devices. The simplest way to solve this is to combine your hover feature with responsive. You can try this: `lg:hover:bg-gray-300`